# Can you create microsites on Pardot?

Tags: pardot

Can you create a microsite through Pardot? Know you can do this in Eloqua, but am wondering if this is also possible through Pardot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Pardot it is known as a Landing Page.

This trailhead (training) might help you out. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/pardot-lead-generation/use-pardot-landing-pages